# udp socket packet loss in unity, using c#

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, udp

I am sending strings out of a unity game to another server program. My strings are around 100 charcters. I am sending approximately 1,000 times a second.

At one second, I start losing massive amounts of data. I am receiving about 15-20% of my data. Does this sound normal?

Thanks, hope I gave enough information.

Comment: Sounds pretty normal to me. Sounds like you filled a buffer in a device right before a slow link.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think this was a large enough amount of data to fill the buffer that fast. How can I fix this? I am new to programming. Thanks

Comment: Send fewer packets with more data. You're still going to have to deal with loss no matter what, but perhaps not quite as much.

Comment: You are sending 100KB/s of data without any protocol overhead if you were using ASCII encoding on the strings. If you are sending 1000 packets a second you are going to have a lot of overhead as well since you need a UDP header for each of the packets.

Comment: How can I send this data with no data loss at all?

Comment: UDP is the wrong standard if you want 100% success rate. You should use TCP if you want that